# connecting from powershell 2.0 to local exchange 2007

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, winrm

I'm trying to connect from my PowerShell to Exchange 2007 (both are on the same computer).

What am I missing?

My code:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy  RemoteSigned  

$cred = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri         
https://localhost/powershell/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
```

The error I get:

```
[localhost] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The server certificate on the destination computer (localhost:443) has the following errors:      
The SSL certificate is expired. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed
Import-PSSession : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
At line:3 char:17
+ Import-PSSession <<<<  $Session
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Import-PSSession], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportPSSessionCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

Remoting does not work with Exchange 2007.  Never has.

Comment: even "remoting" on local??
http://www.o365info.com/2012/07/using-remote-powershell-to-manage_8596.html

Comment: Nope.  Exchannge 2007 RTM came with Powershell V1. There was no remoting capability.  Those Exchange remote management sessions simply do not exist on an Exchange 2007 server.  Support for running the Exchange cmdlets under V2 was added with SP3, in preparation for co-existence with E2010.  Many people tried to get the V2 remoting to work with Exchange 2007, but there were too many incompatibilites. To my knowlege no one was ever able to make that work.